# Why less educated people tend to vote Jokowi?

Tags: voting, indonesia

[This article](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fnasional.kompas.com%2Fread%2F2018%2F02%2F22%2F15572681%2Fsurvei-median-basis-pemilih-jokowi-berpendidikan-rendah) says that Jokowi base is uneducated people.

May be it's a bit controversial. However, Jokowi improves Indonesian corruption perception index. He also deregulate most sectors. He made licensing easy. Indonesia is closer to *laissez-faire* capitalism because of him ([source](https://www.transparency.org/country/IDN)).

I would expect the opposite. I would expect the more educated people to pick Jokowi and the less educated people who may be easily tricked by corrupt officials to do the opposite.

Yet the survey says differently.

Why?

Comment: That public care is a bit controversial. But he did it efficiently. Most of the money would have been corrupted anyway. Also it's pretty efficient.

Comment: I think your comment is good enough as an answer

Comment: "Why?" Because the world is probably so complex that a few indicators cannot predict the success or failure of a politicians, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Jokowi and economical liberalism

You seem to equal "fighting against corruption" with "laissez-faire liberalism". They are not the same thing at all (*some people would even argue than laissez-faire liberalism encourages corruption... a totally different debate*). Some welfare countries have a very low level of corruption (say, Sweden).

In any case, beside fighting corruption, Jokowi's politics cannot be considered as economically ultra-liberal: he introduced a [universal health care system](https://www.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/2015/may/15/indonesias-universal-healthcare-insurance-verdict), tried to develop [public transportations](https://en.tempo.co/read/news/2018/01/03/056914540/AirportTrain-Launched-Jokowi-Asks-People-to-Use-Public-Transport) and upheld several [environmental regulations](https://news.mongabay.com/2016/06/how-is-indonesian-president-jokowi-doing-on-environmental-issues/), notably banning new palm oil exploitations.

- Fighting corruption

Most often policies to reduce corruption are popular with poor people (which strongly correlates with uneducated people).

Who was (and still is) profiting the most from corruption ? Not the uneducated people. Who suffers the most from corruption ? Probably the uneducated people.

Finally, one should note that poor people were the electoral base of Jokowi to begin with, notably because he made poverty one of his major themes during the 2014 campaign.